# Skip all tests of a single project

Tags: unit-testing, gradle, skip

I have a (flat) multi project layout. I'm running gradle 2.1, but an upgrade would be possible.

At the moment I'm migrating an ant build to gradle. For this procedure I would like to exclude/skip/disable a single project from being tested, since its execution takes a long while.

I could only find tips on how to skip tests completely, but that's not what I want, because I also need to run the tests of subsequently added projects, to see if there are any runtime dependencies missing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
gradle -x :your_project_name:test
```

Comment: -X gives me **"Unknown command-line option '-X'."** So I tried -x, which seems to work. I can't say this for sure, because another project hangs when I execute `gradle -x :your_project_name:test` and the build doesn't finish. This only happens when I use the -x option.

Comment: Yes, should be lowercase. If you manage to verify it, please accept.